# How to redirect all except main page with NGINX?

Tags: node.js, nginx

This is my NGINX conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name other.com;
    root        /home/user/html;

        location = / {

        }

        location / {
           return 301 https://mydom.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

It suppose to redirect every request except main route ("/"). But now it redirect everything with main route too. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Looking at your configuration, The URI `/` will be internally redirected to `/index.html`. You will need to add a `location = /index.html { }` block too.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `location = /` block isolates a single URI - the original request.

By default, Nginx processes any request that ends with a `/`, by checking if it resolves to a directory, and checking the directory for any files matching those listed in the `index` directive (default: `index.html`).

The `index` directive causes an *internal redirection* which causes Nginx to repeat the search for a matching `location`.

You will also need to isolate the redirected request.

For example:

```
location = / { }
location = /index.html { }
location / { ... }
```

---

Alternatively, bypass the `index` directive and handle it a single `location` using a `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location = / { try_files /index.html =404; }
location / { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Ahh, perfection. It was the explanation of the additional internal redirect that made it all work. I needed to have nginx redirect everything except root to another site, those first two lines were the key. Put my redirect into the third line.